# Django choice form to determine the class and fields used

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Ideally I would like the user to be presented with two forms, after filling in the 'type' form (Modern/Retro), to then be shown the field attributes specified within the classes.

My forms.py looks like this at the moment to hopefully make it clearer what I'm after:

```
from django import forms
from .import models


class AddGame(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Game
        fields = ['name',
                  'type']
        if type == 'Retro Game':
            model = models.RetroGame
            fields = ['name',
                      'type',
                      'platform',
                      'genre',
                      'slug',
                      'developer',
                      'rom',
                      'bios',
                      'emulator']

        elif type == 'Modern Game':
            model = models.ModernGame
            fields = ['name',
                      'type',
                      'genre',
                      'publisher',
                      'slug',
                      'developer',
                      'online_play']
```

The code below was added for an answer by user quqa123.

What would be wrong with styling my models.py file like this? So there is one base class 'Game' that inherits 'forms.ModelForm', and then two sub classes that inherit from class 'Game'. This way RetroGames and ModernGames both share the attributes in the base class. They both have their own lists and later I can add some other unique attributes to each.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Game(models.Model):


    game_type = (
        ('MG', 'Modern'),
        ('RG', 'Retro'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=game_type)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genre = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    players = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    publisher = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    developer = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RetroGame(Game):


    game_platform = (
        ('PS1', 'PS1'),
        ('PS2', 'PS2'),
        ('XB', 'Xbox'),
        ('NES', 'Nintendo Entertainment System'),
    )
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=game_platform)



class ModernGame(Game):


    game_platform = (
        ('PC', 'PC'),
        ('PS4', 'PS4'),
        ('XB1', 'Xbox One'),
        ('NS', 'Nintendo Switch'),
    )
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=game_platform)
```

Comment: Create 3 forms, and then make the if else in `views.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your code correctly, I think what you are looking for are Database Relationships. You want to have a form that adds a Game to a collection and inside the form you want to choose if its a Retro or Modern game and then depending on the choice give it some attributes. To make it work in good programming practise you basically create three separate models (in your models.py) - Game, RetroGame, and ModernGame and inside of them you make a database relationship One-to-one in your case. More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Here I'll give you example of how it's done:

```
class Game(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   is_retro = models.BooleanField(default=False) # not a good practise
   is_modern = models.BooleanField(default=False) # not a good practise
   # some handling that when one is true other has to be false
   # is needed here 

class RetroGame(models.Model):
   # you dont need a name as Game already has it
   game = models.OneToOneField(Game,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   type = models.CharField()
   ...
   ...
```

But to be honest your code is really 'messy and dirty' and you should design your app in different way - for example make only RetroGame and ModernGame models (omit the Game as it is redundant). Make separate ModelFroms and render them as hidden to your html and using toggle make one of them visible depending on whether the user wants to add Modern Game or Retro Game. Hit me up if you have any questions.

Comment: What would be wrong with styling my models.py in the way shown now in my edited question?

Comment: Now your code is much better, you grouped all common attributes in parent class so as you can see there is less mess and copy paste code. BUT you still have no connection between Game and ModernGame or RetroGame instead of using "choice" field of game_type you should just assign game_type to a OneToOne field link with explanation and example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ Now you have no way to check if a Game object was played on PS1 or PS4 due to lack of connection between a Game object and a ModernGame object. Just read the link docs and you'll be good

Comment: But to be honest its really unnecesary in your case just move your game_platform "choice" field to Game model and completely forget about ModernGame and RetroGame as it gives you no particular advantages its really more of a drawback now. I'm really happy you understood my code and made some improvements but what you really need is a deeper understanding what a model is, where and WHY we use relationships because its more than "cleaning your code" they are very important part of any web application that has some database.

Comment: I recommend you using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLw02n0FEB3E3VSHjyYMcFadtQORvl1Ssj if you wanna get into Web Development as it teaches the basics of web app design and in addition django framework basics. Just pick the videos that are interesting for you and pick 1.5x video speed good luck and have fun :)